# Differing answers when comparing Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica v.10.2

Tags: summation, wolfram-alpha-queries

Out of curiousity, please consider following expression:

```
Sum[(-1)^(n + 1)/n, {n, 1, 100000}]
```

When evaluated using Wolfram Alpha:

Result: `0.693142 - 1.3494*10^-16 I` , complex number

When evaluated using Mathematica v.10.2 (to 6 decimal places):

Result: `0.693142`, rational number

Why Wolfram Alpha evaluates expression stated above to a complex number?

Comment: Pure speculation: Maybe WA evaluates `a^b` as `Exp[Log[a]*b]`. That would give complex numbers in intermediate calculations, where the imaginary part doesn't perfectly cancel out due to numerical inaccuracy. Compare: `Sum[Exp[Log[(-1.)]*(n + 1)]/n, {n, 1, 100000}]` in Mathematica gives a complex result, too (though not the same...)

Comment: After a discussion with my mentor,  he suggested that it must be a rounding error with which I tend to agree. If WA evaluates it as `a^b` it would be rather inefficient although generic at the same time. It's rather curious to say the least.

Comment: `Sum[(-1)^(n + 1)/n, {n, 1, m}] /. m -> 100000.` or `(Sum[(-1)^(n + 1)/n, {n, 1, m}] /. m -> 100000) // N` or `NSum[(-1)^(n + 1)/n, {n, 1, 1000000}] // Chop`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For large enough bounds, `NSum` is used. Compare timings:

```
NSum[(-1)^(n + 1)/n, {n, 1, 100000}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.004744, 0.693142 - 1.3494*10^-16 I}
> ```

```
N[Sum[(-1)^(n + 1)/n, {n, 1, 100000}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.84727, 0.693142}
> ```